# Persisting data larger then context limit across steps in spring batch

Tags: spring, csv, spring-batch

We are using spring batch to process large CSV file with 500K lines. Result of this processing is two things, one line presents one article object and with that we do not have any problems, after chunk is complete we do API call with list of processed articles (1000 per chunk). API endpoint can filter out duplicates so we can process one line at time.

Each line has also quantity and second result should be sum of quantities for same article identifier per location

```
article_code, article_name, size, color, quantity, location, sublocation
123, Nike Shoes, 32, black, 3, store1, sales floor 1
124, Nike shoes, 34, white, 2, store1, sales floor 1
123, Nike Shoes, 32, black, 5, store1, sales floor 2
123, Nike shoes, 32, black, 5, store1, stock room
124, Nike shoes, 34, white, 7, store2, sales floor
123, Nike shoes, 32, black, 3, store2, sales floor
111, Nike shoes, 37, pink, 5, store2, sales floor
```

This should result in 3 articles created and 2 API calls to save stock for each location (article `123` will have quantity of 13 on location `store1`, and 3 in `store2`).

Currently we are having one step which saves articles over rest API and as side effect persist quantities in DB, and other step which pick up that data from DB grouped per location and does API call to save stock.

1. What is good approach for storing data across step if data step is
   larger than limit of `StepContext`?
2. Does spring batch have any elegant way of summing rows in CSV file which are not ordered per some criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For a similar problem we had, we've decided for approach to add new table in same DB where Spring Batch meta tables are, which we clear after every successful run of Job. Flow was:
   Go through CSV file, filter needed data from and in writer save "articles". While doing that we aggregated data in table. When this step finishes then you read data from new table and save "stocks" in new step.
2. I don't think so. This could also be very heavy and costly operation so that's why Spring people didn't bother implementing it.
   I suppose you can create your own ItemReader and override behavior on afterPropertiesSet to do ordering by criteria, but on files with 500k lines, you would need to do all the buffering, memory managment and also that way you are reading file at least 2 times wich is big overhead.